# Dapper with SQL Server output bigint parameter returns int32

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper, sqldatatypes, output-parameter

I have the following C# code and a SQL Server stored procedure.

```
private static long GetTestBigintOutput(SqlConnection dbConn) 
{
    var sqlParams = new DynamicParameters();
    sqlParams.Add("@input_param", 1);
    sqlParams.Add("@output_param", SqlDbType.BigInt, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

    dbConn.Execute("stp_zzz_test_output_bigint", sqlParams, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    var output = sqlParams.Get<long>("@output_param");

    return output;
}

static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

    try 
    {
        var output = GetTestBigintOutput(GetDbConnection());
        Console.WriteLine($"Output = {output}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);                
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stp_zzz_test_output_bigint
    (@input_param bigint,
     @output_param bigint OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @output_param = @input_param  
END
```

The output of this simple console app is

> Hello World!
> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int64'.

Is this to be expected? My other stored procedures return values that are tied to `BIGINT` columns, but the actual returned value will fit in an `Int32`. However I can't be sure beforehand what the actual returned value will be and this will change once the program is running.

I know I can change the

```
var output = sqlParams.Get<long>("@output_param");
```

to

```
var output = sqlParams.Get<dynamic>("@output_param");
```

However I feel that this is a kind of cheating.

Any thoughts?

regards
Paul

Comment: Try changing 
`var output = sqlParams.Get<long>("@output_param");`
to
`var output = sqlParams.Get<Int64>("@output_param");`

Refer [this link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) for mapping of datatypes between SQL and C#

Comment: Try to define the **input parameter** to also be of `BigInt` type:  `sqlParams.Add("@input_param", SqlDbType.BigInt, 1);`

Comment: @HemantHalwai, `long` is just a language specific alias for `System.Int64`. They are the very same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the `Add` method of `DynamicParameters` accepts `SqlDbType` as the `dbType` parameter. It should be `DbType` instead, so you can try to change following:

```
sqlParams.Add("@output_param", SqlDbType.BigInt, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
```

to that:

```
sqlParams.Add("@output_param", dbType: DbType.Int64, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
```

Comment: beat me to it :) but yes, this ^^^

Comment: tried changig it to sqlParams.Add("@output_param", DbType.Int64, direction: ParameterDirection.Output); and var output = sqlParams.Get<Int64>("@output_param"); Still the same result

Comment: Try to be explicit where you want to pass your arguments by specifying a name. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments. Most likely you passed `DbType` at the wrong position.

Comment: Thanks, using a named param did the trick.. Once you see it, it is easy..